# Can't use a type parameter inside a generic Functions in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following function :

```
const getDefaultFilterObjFromKeys: 
   <Key extends keyof FilterFields>(keys: Key[]) => IFiltersState<Key> =
      (keys) => {
         if (keys.length === 0){
            throw Error("empty Arr")
         }
         const defaults = {}
         Object.entries(_.pick(filterFields, keys)).forEach(
            ([key, filterField]) => {
               defaults[key] = filterField.defaultVal
            },
         )
         return defaults as IFiltersState<Key>
      }
```

I get an error that the return type doesn't match the defined return type. I believe it does, but Typescript has a difficult time recognizing the actual return type for various reasons (it can't recognize that the keys array could not be empty, and there are a few calculations and manipulations), so either ignoring the error or casting is required. I'd rather cast, but in order to cast I need to be able to use the Key type parameter within the function. When I try to do so I get an error `Cannot find name Key`. Is there any syntax in which I could use the type parameter within the function to cast?

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev, In retrospect, the issue described in this question is that I can't use the Key type parameter inside the function when I define the function in such a way. So keeping this in mind, I don't think FilterFields or IFiltersState types will are necessary to understand this issue. In retrospect and taking into account the principle of minimality - if anything I'd shorten the question and code :-) .

Answer (score 2):

It's because your signature is syntax is wrong, so you're ending up with a nested arrow function and `Key` is out of scope. There's really no need to define functions with `const = () =>` unless you're worried about binding, so you can just make it more readable with the function keyword:

```
function getDefaultFilterObjFromKeys<Key extends keyof FilterFields>(keys: Key[]): IFiltersState<Key> {
  if (keys.length === 0){
    throw Error("empty Arr")
  }
  const defaults = {}
  Object.entries(_.pick(filterFields, keys)).forEach(
    ([k, filterField]) => {
      defaults[k] = filterField.defaultVal
    },
  )
  return defaults as IFiltersState<Key>
}
```

If you did want to use const the proper signature syntax would be:

```
const getDefaultFilterObjFromKeys2 = <Key extends keyof FilterFields>(keys: Key[]): IFiltersState<Key> => {
  if (keys.length === 0){
    throw Error("empty Arr")
  }
  const defaults = {}
  Object.entries(_.pick(filterFields, keys)).forEach(
    ([k, filterField]) => {
      defaults[k] = filterField.defaultVal
    },
  )
  return defaults as IFiltersState<K>
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Robbie, I'm used to separate the type of the function and the function itself: `const functionName: FunctionType = (params) => {function Body}`. Is there any way to write a generic function in this structure?

Comment: yep, see my second example, that would be the syntax. You can move the function signature to after the name if you'd like: `const getDefaultFilterObjFromKeys2: <Key extends keyof FilterFields>(keys: Key[]) => IFiltersState<Key> = (keys)` but that is more verbose with no real difference in type safety its really just a matter of taste

Comment: you might be right- it's more verbose with no real difference. However, the definitions you just wrote is exactly the definition I originally used, and as you correctly observed it didn't work - Key was not recognized in the function, and even VSCode got confused about this syntax. I used this syntax succesfully before but not for generic functions.

Comment: oh woops I made a typo `const getDefaultFilterObjFromKeys2: <Key extends keyof FilterFields>(keys: Key[]) => IFiltersState<Key> = <Key>(keys: Key[])` you have to pass it as a generic type param, which imo is even worse

Comment: this becomes even more verbose, I tried it, and for some reason VSCode had a difficult time recognizing what's going on, and all the colors got messed up.

Answer (score 1):

Following @Robbie's answer and comments.

```
const function1: <I>(arg:I) => I = (arg) => {....}
const function2 = <I>(arg:I):I{...}
```

are not entirely equivalent. One of the distinctions is that in function 2 you could use the type parameter inside the body of the function. To be able to use the type parameter when writing the function in the first form, you have to define the type parameter as part of the function itself.

```
const function1: <I>(arg:I) => I = <I>(arg:I) => {....}
```

This makes our code even more verbose, so one might prefer the form used to write function2 in such cases.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd write it if I were you. You didn't gave me an answer for my request (I've deleted that comment) so I had to improvise in some places. I removed lodash and replaced `Object.entries` with a more simple `Object.keys`.

Also, from my experience you should always separate types (interfaces) from implementations. That's what I did. This however doesn't mean that you won't need to duplicate some type variables (`Key`) when you need them in the implementation part as well.

The main idea you probably are missing is: 
**You had your `Key` missing because you defined it in the constraining type, but not in the implementation function**

```
const filterFields = {
    foo: {
        defaultVal: 123
    }
}

type FilterFields = typeof filterFields

interface IFiltersState<K> = {

}

interface GetDefaultFilterObjFromKeys {
    <Key extends keyof FilterFields>(keys: Key[]): IFiltersState<Key>
}

const getDefaultFilterObjFromKeys:
GetDefaultFilterObjFromKeys =
    <Key extends keyof FilterFields>(keys: Key[]) => {
        if (keys.length === 0) {
            throw Error("empty Arr")
        }
        const defaults: {
            [K in keyof FilterFields]: FilterFields[K]['defaultVal']
        } = {} as any;

        (Object.keys(filterFields) as Key[]).forEach(
            key => {
                if (!keys.includes(key)) {
                    return
                }
                defaults[key] = filterFields[key].defaultVal
            },
        )
        return defaults
    }
```